# HTML Agility Pack ignores <br> tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I wrote the following code in C# to retrieve the contents of a table in a web-page (After taking permission for that). It works almost perfect but some of the cells contains multiple values like this

```
 _______
|   10  |
|   11  |
|   12  |
|___13__|
```

But I get the value `10111213` instead.

Here's a link so you could take a look the the table code if needed for further clear vision:
ttps://ug3.technion.ac.il/rishum/course/104031

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string page = webClient.DownloadString("https://ug3.technion.ac.il/rishum/course/104031");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);

List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='rishum-groups']")
            .Descendants("tr")
            .Skip(1)
            .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `InnerText` property will remove all elements, leaving only the text. If you want to keep the `<br>` elements, you should use `InnerHtml` instead. Here's an example:

```cs
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='rishum-groups']")
            .Descendants("tr")
            .Skip(1)
            .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerHTML.Trim()).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

If you need to parse those values, you can use the `Split()` method on the string. Here's an example:

```cs
var myValues = myTextField.Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```